# There are two types of color mixing: Additive and Subtractive. How about XOR-ive color?

Tags: color

There are two types of color mixing: Additive and Subtractive. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_mixing

Is is possible that color mixing model be done in XOR?

Comment: Quick answer: There is bilinear color mixing. This is applied on each individual channel `C` = { R, G or B }, one at a time. Let `C1` be the value from first input, range from 0.0 to 1.0; `C2` be from the second input. Let `f00, f01, f10, f11` be four weights. These weights must be non-negative, and must add up to 1.0. Then, `Cmix = f00 + f01 * C1 + f10 * C2 + f11 * C1 * C2` gives the bilinear mix of the color `C1` and `C2`. Not posting as answer because I won't be giving any citation or sources for it.

Comment: @est: if you like, you can call any kind of function a "mixing function" if it takes two color values, does some mathematical operation on it and returns a new color. But for what purpose? The operation should make some sense - just applying an operator like XOR because "it's there" does not seem very meaningful to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly. Additive and subtractive colour models are based on continuous physical phenomena, while XOR is a discrete operation lacking a real-world optical counterpart.

Subtractive colour models are based on mixing of pigments, which absorb certain frequencies of light and reflect others—red paint, for example, absorbs non-red frequencies from white (full-spectrum) light and thus reflects red hues. Additive colour models are based on mixing of light frequencies, as with a computer monitor.

The key thing to understand, though, is that *additive* and *subtractive* don’t refer to *addition* and *subtraction* in the algebraic sense, but rather in the frequency-response sense, which is more akin to audio mixing.

Comment: add/sub could make some algebraic sense. E.g. [in RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_color#Additive_secondaries) red+green= yellow, green+blue=cyan, but how about yellow+cyan?

Comment: @est: Yes, you can think of colour addition as (usu. clamped) vector addition in a particular colour space. However, colour spaces are best approximations of particular *aspects* of colour, such as monitor gamuts (RGB), printing inks (CMYK), and human perception (LAB), as well as various overlaps of these (sRGB, HSV, HSL). It’s not a simple issue!

Answer (score 5):

Additive and subtractive mixing can be defined in terms of formulas that approximate certain real-world properties (mixing of coloured light, mixing of paint, application of successive coloured filters etc.)

XOR doesn't really make sense in this context, for two reasons:

- XOR works with binary values, 1 and 0 (or true and false). It isn't normally defined on continuous values, which is what you need if you are dealing with colour spaces
- What real world property are you trying to model? To my knowledge, there is nothing in nature that displays XOR-like colour mixing behaviour.

You could, of course, define an artificial mixing function that exhibits XOR-like behaviour at extreme values (0.0 and 1.0) and does something else in between. You might even get some interesting visual effects. But it's not a standard technique.

Comment: Not only binary, XOR could be applied to integer values. We don't process color as continuous on computers, they are all digital (like 0-255).